# What reputation is needed to get the k?

Tags: support, reputation, si-prefix

How many thousands of reputation points are necessary before the score is converted from n,000 to nk?

Comment: 10k? I do not remember seeing any lower rep being shown in nk format...

Comment: Yeah, I remember seeing 6k and 7k back in the day.  But since I've reached that, I still don't have the k.  :)  So I'm guessing that was changed.  Just curious to what (what it's at now).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

10,000 reputation, exactly.

The system doesn't start rounding until then.

[image]

Comment: Go markus, one more vote!