# How is the reputation value formatted when it gets abbreviated?

Tags: support, reputation, user-interface

The current reputation value (rep) of StackOverflow (SO) users is mostly shown in a short form beside their name on all possible occasions. I see values like `1`, `23`, `345`, `12.3k` or `456k`. Just out of interest: what abbreviation rule works behind it?

I found a partial answer on this question [What reputation is needed to get the k?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91356/238205) which leads to the conclusion that after 9,999 follows 10k, but that's just a guess, since 10,0k would also make sense, i.e. it's not clear how many digits will be shown and how/if rounding is involved (or truncating).

I think a tiny comment added to some help page should describe **how** the rep value is actually formatted in the SO pages?

Comment: @ChrisF I think my question isn't a duplicate. The question http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91356/238205 that I already referred to asks for the meaning of `k` which was quite clear to me. I'm also interested in the number of digits (=precision).

Comment: This is not a feature request, you don't suggest anything to add or change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purely based on my own observations, the formatting seems to be:

- The number itself until 9,999 (using , as a delimiter between thousands and hundreds)
- The amount of thousands with a 'k' in the end with the following rules:

  - The resulting number will have 3 digits (10.1k, 32.5k, 123k) rounded to the closest number using normal rounding rules (0-4 round down, 5-9 round up).
  - *But* if the reputation after rounding would be `<thousands>.0`, the `.0` is left out resulting in only 2 digits (11k, 42k)

These rules would seem to work up to 999k.

Comment: The thousands/hundreds delimiter appears to be localised. I have a comma.

Comment: @Joe How on earth did I miss that..

Comment: Someone will have to ask [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) to write a new rule when he ultimately breaks this one.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your observations, especially the rounding rules (including 0-truncation). I doubt that this question will ever get an "official answer", so I'll check-mark this one.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this, which exactly does the same thing as SO does.

```
public static string ReadableReps(int reps)
{
   if (reps < 10000)
   {
       return reps.ToString("N0"); // or just N for culture specific
   }
   else return Math.Round(reps / 1000.0, 1) + "k";
}
```

Comment: +1 ...SO seems to use only the English notation for numbers.